# How do I implement text fields with autocomplete for habtm fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scriptaculous

I tried the example from Rails Cookbook and managed to get it to work. However the `text_field_with_auto_complete` works only for one value.

```
class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

In the New Expense View rhtml

```
<%= text_field_with_auto_complete :category, :name %>
```

Auto complete works for the first category. How do I get it working for multiple categories? e.g. Category1, Category2
*Intended behavior: like the StackOverflow Tags textbox*

**Update:**
With some help and some more tinkering, I got multiple comma-seperated autocomplete to show up (will post code-sample here).
*However on selection, the last value replaces the content of the text_field_with_auto_complete.* So instead of Category1, Category2.. the textbox shows Category2 when the second Category is selected via auto-complete. Any ideas how to rectify this?

Comment: I think this blog post covers what you're looking for: <a href="http://seanmountcastle.com/2005/10/21/ajax-autocompletion-with-rails/">AJAX autocompletion with Rails</a>.

Comment: Nice pathway... a custom auto_complete_for_model_attribute method in the controller. Cleared that hurdle.. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to support multiple instances of autocomplete per field, you can pass a delimiter to the autocomplete options  with the symbol :token.  This provides a delimiter to allow multiple results.   Stackoverflow would use :token => ' ' (there should be a space between the quotes, but the autoformat is removing it) to specify space at the delimiter between multiple takes although ',' is more commonly used.

Comment: Can you post a code-sample? I couldn't get this :token / :tokens option to work

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite your question, but I wouldn't recommend using HABTM anymore.  You should create a join model and use has_many :through.  (In your case you'd create a new model called ExpenseCategoryAssignment, or something)

The problem is that HABTM creates ambiguities that rails doesn't like, and it tends to expose bugs you wouldn't see otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "data-delimiter" param like this
`<%= f.autocomplete_field :brand_name, welcome_autocomplete_brand_name_path, "data-delimiter" => ', ' %>`